# « En » et « Dans » sont-ils interchangeables dans « J’ai foi en/dans ses capacités langagières »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions

> J’ai foi **en/dans** ses capacités langagières.

Merci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux expriment la même idée et on peut dire, je le crois, que l'usage de « en » (dans le cas présent) est assez littéraire en comparaison, mais que cela n'empêche aucunement de l'employer dans la langue parlée.

On peut s'intéresser à la distribution des deux possibilités au cours des décennies passées et s'apercevoir que jusqu'aux années 1950 il existait une fréquence d'utilisation des deux approximativement égale au cours du temps, ce qui pourrait porter à croire (mais seulement porter à croire) qu'il n'y avait pas de différence entre les deux. La marge d'avance enregistrée pour « en » depuis 1950 pourrait alors être imputée à une vogue. Bien qu'une conjecture intéressante cela reste dans le domaine des possibilités.

[image]

Il faut néanmoins se rendre compte qu'il existe en rapport avec ce choix de préposition une question d'idiomaticité avec laquelle on  peut difficilement transiger.

Les cas suivants sont exclusifs de l'autre possibilité.

- foi en Dieu, foi en lui, foi en Jésus, foi en le siècle, foi en son général,

[image]

Les deux sont utilisés.

- foi en/dans la parole de, foi en/dans l'Évangile, foi en/dans un monde,

On peut dire, je pense, que pour des locutions non établies (à la différence de  « (([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/foi)) Loc. verb. Avoir foi en/dans qqn, qqc.; avoir foi dans le témoignage de qqn; avoir foi dans le progrès, en son étoile, en l'avenir, dans sa chance, foi en son général; avoir foi dans son médecin), les deux possibilités sont correctes, et il faut se méfier de ce qui est utilisé en pratique ; par exemple, on ne trouve que « foi en un juste … » mais au féminin les deux sont utilisés ; Il est donc nécessaire d'accepter « foi en un juste … » comme tout à fait correct (par exemple, « foi en un juste partage des responsabilités »).

[image]

[image]